# java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: input == null! Even though other images load

Tags: java

I'm making a game and I need to load a large amount of images into custom sprites. The first 59 work, but randomly It stops working at weapon 5.

Here is the error I get:

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.ExceptionInInitializerError
    at rendering.Pinpoint.<init>(Pinpoint.java:27)
    at start.SCCMAIN$RenderThread.<init>(SCCMAIN.java:67)
    at start.SCCMAIN.<init>(SCCMAIN.java:34)
    at start.SCCMAIN.main(SCCMAIN.java:210)
Caused by: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: input == null!
    at javax.imageio.ImageIO.read(Unknown Source)
    at rendering.Sprite.<init>(Sprite.java:151)
    at rendering.Sprite.<clinit>(Sprite.java:76)
    ... 4 more
```

Here is the code I have that creates the sprites:

```
...public static final Sprite Core1=new Sprite(22,22,"/assets/main/images/parts/Core_1.PNG");
public static final Sprite Core2=new Sprite("/assets/main/images/parts/Core_2.PNG");
public static final Sprite Core3=new Sprite("/assets/main/images/parts/Core_3.PNG");
public static final Sprite Core4=new Sprite("/assets/main/images/parts/Core_4.PNG");
public static final Sprite Center1=new Sprite("/assets/main/images/parts/Center_1.PNG");
public static final Sprite Ability1=new Sprite("/assets/main/images/weapons/weapon_1.PNG");
public static final Sprite Ability2=new Sprite("/assets/main/images/weapons/weapon_2.PNG");
public static final Sprite Ability3=new Sprite("/assets/main/images/weapons/weapon_3.PNG");
public static final Sprite Ability4=new Sprite("/assets/main/images/weapons/weapon_4.PNG");
public static final Sprite Ability5=new Sprite("/assets/main/images/weapons/weapon_5.PGN");
public static final Sprite Ability6=new Sprite("/assets/main/images/weapons/weapon_6.PGN");...
```

And here is the Sprite constructor:

```
public Sprite(String s)
{
    try {
        this.image=ImageIO.read(getClass().getResourceAsStream(s));
    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    this.doubledOffSetX=this.image.getWidth();
    this.doubledOffSetY=this.image.getHeight();
    this.id=currentId;
    Sprite.currentId++;
    System.out.println(Sprite.getCurrentId());
}
```

EDIT: Turns out I had named weapon 5+ as a PGN file instead of a PNG file.

Comment: Are you sure weapon5 is properly named? The extension for it and weapon 6 reads `PGN` instead of `PNG`

Comment: Oh wow that's the one place I didn't check. Thanks, sorry for asking a dumb question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**What is a PGN file?**
The .pgn file extension is most commonly associated with Picatinny Arsenal Electronic Formstore image files. The PGN files are a TIFF file format used by Picatinny Arsenal Electronic Formstore. The PGN files are compressed image files stored in a lossless compression format.

PGN files are indeed images, but it seems like ImageIO does not support this format, look at the specification http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/javax/imageio/package-summary.html